# owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `` vs ``) for key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use `context`in Reactjs but I keep getting this warning from react i have tried playing with it as much as i can but nothing seems to work,

I read the post they send you too with all the comments, Didn't help much.

Followed a few online tutorials but cant seem to solve my problem, I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

the error: ``` Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `` vs ``) for key (filterItems) while mounting CategorieChooser ```

here is the layout basically

> ```
> var Application = React.createClass({
>     childContextTypes: {
>          filterItems: React.PropTypes.array
>     },
>     getChildContext: function() {
>          return { filterItems: [] };
>     },
>     render: function() {
>       return (
>         <div>
>           <Banner />
>           <CategorieChooser />
>         </div>
>       );
>     }
> }); 
> var CategorieChooser = React.createClass({
>   contextTypes: {
>   filterItems: React.PropTypes.array
>  },
>   ...
> })
> ```

Comment: which version of react do you use ?

Comment: I can't reproduce it in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DkAUXQfT9Q3QxyzOxHcD?p=preview

Comment: aww man... i forgot to change the path to react it was 13.0 before, damn it!